# PHP AES 128 ECB Ciphers and Delphi AES 128 ECB

Tags: php, delphi, encryption, cryptography

I'm encryption "sifrelenecek" string with Delphi using AES 128 ECB using key as "KRPTTT101103" and it gives me "FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56", i'm checking with http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ and it's correct. I'm trying to create same encryption with php using this function ;

```
function sifrele($str, $key){
 $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael_128', 'ecb');
 $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
 $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
 return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)); }

print sifrele("sifrelenecek","KRPTTT101103")
```

but php gives me the result as "+wL2yf+72thixicjw0duQA==", how can i encrypt in Delphi and Decrypt in php or the opposit ?

Searched on the web and found so many functions but not any of those functions results are the same with Delphi or http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your Delphi cipher gives you hex representation of encrypted text, while PHP cipher returns BASE64 encoded representation.

Comment: @Marko thanks for your response, i was thinking the same way, but in that web site how did they exactly get the same result, that's what i'm trying to do, it took almost my all day and i coluldn't figure it out.

Comment: The problem is that you're using base64_encode() function in PHP. I don't know PHP at all, but you have to encode mcrypt_encrypt() return value to hex, not to base64. bintohex() maybe.

Comment: You probably want [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex), which will take the binary garbage that mcrypt_encrypt spits out and convert it to a less-unfriendly hex string.

Comment: You need to think about the code and understand what you are doing. One variant is clearly encoded using hex. The other with base64. And it's right there in the code you use. You won't get anywhere by trying things at random without actually endeavouring to understand them. And you are doing crypto too. Never something to be done with a lack of understanding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are right about that perspective,the problem is i'm Delphi developer and very very rookie about php, my project is including that part of php that's why i'm trying to understand and work it out,i'm still searching about how i can do it.

Comment: You have to read and understand the code. Look at the base64 encode. You do need to understand that crypto operates on binary data. So it's already dubious to pass a string. How do you encode the string as binary. And then when it's encoded as binary, how to represent that. Do you understand text encodings and what is meant by binary?

Comment: @moskito-x i did, thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see you try to compare one which is clearly encoded using hex. The other with base64.

in php

- let the pading away(this is done automatically).
- don't do a **base64_encode** (that you have also not done in delphi).

---

php manual

Description :

---

> string mcrypt_encrypt ( string $cipher , string $key ,
>   string $data , string $mode [, string $iv ] )
>
> Encrypts the data and returns it.
>
> ......
>
> data
>
> The data that will be encrypted with the given cipher and mode. If
>   the size of the data   is not n * blocksize, the data will be padded
>   with '\0'.
>
> The returned crypttext can be larger than the size of the data
>   that was given by data.

ECB mode ignores the IV, so it is misleading to show an example using both MCRYPT_MODE_ECB and an IV (the example in the manual shows the same thing).  Also, it's important to know that ECB is useful for random data, but structured data should use a stronger mode like MCRYPT_MODE_CBC

php Code

```
function encrypt($input) {
    // $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
    $mcr = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "KRPTTT101103",
                          $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $hex2 = bin2hex($mcr); // Convert binary data into hexadecimal representation
    return strtoupper($hex2);
    // base64_encode($mcr);
    }

$encryptedhextext = encrypt("sifrelenecek");

 if ($encryptedhextext == "FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56" ) {
   echo   "Encrypted Hex text in Delphi and php are equal<br />";    
   echo $encryptedhextext." == FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56";
 }
```

**Output**

Encrypted Hex text in Delphi and php are equal
FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56 == FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56

Comment: thanks for explanation, after i read the comments and answer i just realised i'm much more lower than a rookie about php, after this project i really need to work on php. But for once is there any chance to give me two functions for decrypt delphi's data and encrypt again as delphi did with php ? Sorry from everyone i'm stuck and I'm really desperate about it.

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing two different forms of padding. This is what is causing the mismatch. It's not merely a Base64/hex difference.

Your plaintext is 12 bytes: "sifrelenecek", encoded as:

```
[115, 105, 102, 114, 101, 108, 101, 110, 101, 99, 101, 107]
```

If you pad the plaintext with **ZEROES**, as apparently Delphi does, and as mcrypt_encrypt is documented as doing, then you are encrypting:

```
[115, 105, 102, 114, 101, 108, 101, 110, 101, 99, 101, 107, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The resulting ciphertext is **++SkQF1sG1RQPZshPkGuVg==** in Base64 which, when decoded to plain bytes and re-encoded in hex, becomes "FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56" -- just what the online tool returns.

But if you pad the plaintext with **PKCS#7 padding**, as you do in your PHP code above:

```
$pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
$str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
```

then this plaintext is padded with FOURS and you are encrypting:

```
[115, 105, 102, 114, 101, 108, 101, 110, 101, 99, 101, 107, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

The resulting ciphertext is **+wL2yf+72thixicjw0duQA==** -- just what you show above in your question.

Either pad on both sides with ZEROES, or pad on both sides with PKCS#7, and your results should match.

Comment: I have faced the same problem in the past and had to result to padding with zeroes. That's because I was using DCPCrypt which does that by default. The OP does not state what Delphi code he uses, so his options might be broader.

Comment: Note that you should use PKCS#7 padding if you want to encrypt binary data. Zero padding only works if the plaintext does not end with `00` valued characters. Also note that ECB is not safe for most purposes, *including* encryption of text.

Comment: @JimFlood :  It's not true `++SkQF1sG1RQPZshPkGuVg==` is not equal `FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56` you are also mixing `++SkQF1sG1RQPZshPkGuVg==` in hex = `2b2b536b5146317347315251505a7368506b477556673d3`

Comment: @moskito-x: if you Base64-decode the string '++SkQF1sG1RQPZshPkGuVg==', and then hex-encode the resulting byte array, you will get "FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56". The hex string "2b2b536b5146317347315251505a7368506b477556673d3" is literally, the ASCII string "++SkQF1sG1RQPZshPkGuVg==" in hex, i.e. 0x2b is '+', 0x2b is '+', 0x53 is 'S', 0x6b is 'k', etc. I meant the binary ciphertext hex-encoded, not the Base64 string.

Comment: So this is put in your answer can be easily misunderstood : `The resulting ciphertext is ++SkQF1sG1RQPZshPkGuVg== (in Base64) -- just what the online tool returns (i.e. the same value, in hex.)`

Comment: It is much easier to explain to the OP that he should just take the value of `mcrypt_encrypt()`  **before** he does `base64_encode`. For what he needs for ever `base64_encode` ? OP wrote `with Delphi using AES 128 ECB using key as "KRPTTT101103" and it gives me "FBE4A4405D6C1B54503D9B213E41AE56"` And that is clearly without `base64_encode`.

Comment: @moskito-x I disagree. The OP gets the same result from the online tool as from Delphi, as stated in the question, and clearly, this is using ZERO padding. The OP is using PKCS#7 padding as shown both in the provided code, and in the Base64 result shown in the question. Base64 vs. hex does absolutely nothing to solve this mismatch. It will never work if both ends use different padding.